# setting object through variable containing strings not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have developed a pretty basic audio player on on my website similar to SoundClouds.

I have managed to successfully finish it, and I am starting to clean up all the markup, including (trying) removing all inline event handlers **(i.e: `onclick=""` or `onkeyup=""`)**.

However, I have come across a bit of a problem in my JavaScript whilst doing this.

It's a bit hard to explain so I'm going to post my JavaScript, then give you an idea of what the problem is:

```
$(".track-w__trigger").click(function(){
    var tid = $(this).attr('aria-trackid'); // aria-trackid is equal to a random integer created by PHP
    var tiW = 'w' + tid + 'w'; // this is an object (i.e: w3w)
    playPauseButton(this, tiW, ti);
});

function playPauseButton(button, wave, trackID){
    var button = $(button);

    if(wave.isPlaying()){ // the object (w3w.isPlaying())
        button.removeClass("playing");
        wave.pause();
    } else {
        button.addClass("playing"); 
        wave.play();
    }
}
```

What I used to have was

```
<div class="track-w__trigger" onclick="playPauseButton(this, w3w, 3)" id="w3w-trigger"></div>
```

and now it is:

```
<div class="track-w__trigger" aria-trackid="3" id="w3w-trigger"></div>
```

As you can see in the second block of code. `w3w` is an object. However, because I have set it using my `click` function in a separate `script` using string quotes. **JavaScript** has gone ahead and made it a `string`.

So now when I use `wave.isPlaying()` for example; it does nothing.

I have no idea how to fix this, and no result on Google will help me. Any help in fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

This is where & how `w3w` is set:

```
var w3w = Uki.start({
    // e.t.c
});
```

Comment: what is `w3w`? and where is setted?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi one moment, editing my code

Comment: @ParthTrivedi edited!

Comment: you have set it in this place as a string isn't it ?
var tiW = 'w' + ti + 'w'; and what is the ti variable will it change dynamically

Comment: @GraveyardQueen yeah, but because it has quotes, it is no longer an object. If I were to do `var tiW = w + ti + w`, it would give me an error.

Comment: will the ti variable change dynamically?that is according to the track number?

Comment: it stays the same. However, if another track is clicked with the `aria-trackid` attribute being `4`, yes it will.

Comment: i hope `ti` is `tid` or what is `ti`?

Comment: try to use eval    `wave = eval(wave);`  to evaluate the string as a function

Comment: @madalinivascu sorry, yes it is. I accidentally forgot to add the `d` on the end of `ti`. Thanks for point this out to me :-)

Comment: @madalinivascu I managed to get it working! thankyou!! :) should post as an answer ;) will select as fixed

Comment: @badjuju added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eval 
`wave = eval(wave);`
 to evaluate the string as a function

or use a safer way

```
wave = window[wave];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zmr412q7/

Comment: eval is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Joe whys that?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having each object as a seperate variable, create an object that contains each object at the id representing the N in wNw. Ex:

```
var wNw = {};

// represents w1w
wNw[1] = (Uki.start({
    // e.t.c
}));

// represents w17w
wNw[17] = (Uki.start({
    // e.t.c
}));

// represents w3w
wNw[3] = (Uki.start({
    // e.t.c
}));
```

This gives you an object that looks like:

```
{
   1: object_that_was_w1w
   17: object_that_was_w17w
   3: object_that_was_w13w
}
```

And then your click handler looks like this:

```
$(".track-w__trigger").click(function(){
    var tid = $(this).attr('aria-trackid'); // aria-trackid is equal to an integer of 1 to 5
    var tidNum = parseInt(tid);
    playPauseButton(this, wNw[tidNum], ti);
});
```

Comment: This won't work unfortunately :/ Due to PHP generating those numbers as the page is scrolled down (making the integer of 5 increase). I have made an edit to the comment in my post. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```js
var tid='w'+5+'w';
var tryout=tid.valueOf();
console.log("getting the object "+tryout)
```

The valueOf property converts the string to an object